# Merge and "unfold" referencing row values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a structure containing items which **may** consist of another items sequentially. Every item is associated with cost and one `in_item` may be a component of multiple items. It looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'out_item': [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8],
    'in_item': [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 3],
    'in_item_cost': [5, 10, 15, 20, 54, 10]})

df
   out_item  in_item  in_item_cost
0         1        2             5
1         2        3            10
2         3        4            15
3         4        5            20
4         7        8            54
5         8        3            10
```

I would like to somehow "unfold" those sequences to make this structure:

```py
   out_item  in_item  in_item_cost
0         1        2             5
1         1        3            10
2         1        4            15
3         1        5            20
4         7        8            54
5         7        3            10
6         7        4            15
5         7        5            20
```

I don't know the order of the `out_items` and `in_items` and the amount of resulting rows for `out_items`. I tried merging the df to itself, however, it does not solve the problem of finding  non-unique `out_items` and doing it somewhat "recursively". Moreover, unmelting nor unstacking seem to me to be not sufficient here.

The dataset is huge, so only vectorised approaches may be considered here.

Comment: may be you can try networkx here..

Comment: DiGraph could be an option here, thanks for this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a function `unfold` that uses `networkx` to create a `Digraph` to map the relationship between `out_item` and `in_item`:

```
import networkx as nx

def unfold():
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'out_item', 'in_item', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
    M = df.drop_duplicates('in_item').set_index('in_item')['in_item_cost']
    for i in df['out_item'].loc[lambda x: ~x.isin(df['in_item'])]:
        n = nx.descendants(G, i)
        yield [[i]*len(n), [*n], M[n].tolist()]

out = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(unfold()).T, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print(out)

   out_item  in_item  in_item_cost
0         1        2             5
1         1        3            10
2         1        4            15
3         1        5            20
4         7        8            54
5         7        3            10
6         7        4            15
7         7        5            20
```

Comment: It works as intended, however I got a warning there: `FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.`.

Comment: @pdaawr simply replace `np.hstack(unfold())` with `np.hstack(list(unfold()))` and warning will disappear..